# Finding the rightmost element in an array of duplicate elements using binary search

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms, arrays, binary-search

i was reading Binary Search in the wikipedia and i came across this part of 'rightmost index of an element in an array of duplicate elements'. i understood the process of determining the leftmost index, but for rightmost index, i am unable to get it.

Here is the link :
[Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#CITEREFKasaharaMorishita2006)

Algorithm:

```
function binary_search_rightmost(A, n, T):
L := 0
R := n
while L < R:
    m := floor((L + R) / 2)
    if A[m] > T:
        R := m
    else:
        L := m + 1
return L - 1
```

**How the  the while loop content is derived** (Any logical explanation  or example)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @orlp  , i am unable to understand the content of while loop.

Comment: Take a sorted array with duplicates (say some 10 elements), and play around with the code. That should clarify what is going on.